# Did Jesse have a different disorder than what he indicated?

Tags: character, fast-and-furious-franchise, fast-and-furious-1

The character of Jesse in Dom Torreto's team in the original *The Fast and the Furious* was interesting but didn't get much screen time.

In a conversation with Brian, he said something about having *Attention Deficit Disorder* and failing everything except math.  Typically, students with ADD do struggle with academics (take it from me), but he mentioned an aptitude for math.

Combined with his avid interest in engines ("Engines just calmed me") (and computer-aided design) could it be possible that he would be more accurately described as being on the Autism Spectrum?  Perhaps <strike>Asperger's Disease</strike> Asperger Syndrome?

Given the time-frame of film and release, I would understand ADD being more accepted and familiar to audiences.  If the film were remade today, would the diagnosis have changed?

Comment: Or just the awareness of autism, asperger's and other disorders was too small back then, and maybe even the writers have never heard of them and only knew of ADD, since that was the most often diagnosed disorder in kids in schools.

Comment: @TK-421, that's what I was thinking.  Since shows like *The Big Bang Theory* personality quirks are a little more celebrated

Comment: My step-son has ADHD and takes to math and science like a the nerd that he is. Nothing else matters much otherwise. So, Jesse can have ADD and be a math nerd.

Comment: @SiXandSeven8ths, Kudos to your stepson.  Math and Science are the most rewarding subjects in my opinion to be good at.  My question stems from the specific failures at all other subjects, combined with a comforting interest that will calm a person.  These are the symptoms that would align more to someone on the Autism Spectrum.  Perhaps, I could have phrased this better

Comment: @m1gp0z I understood what you were asking, however, I was merely mentioning that my stepson has similar qualities to the character of Jesse. Very smart, but easily distracted, while still finding things that can keep him occupied for hours on end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Inconclusive

One of my favorite questions on this site deals with Peter Venkman of the *Ghostbusters* and whether or not he is narcissistic.

The challenge with fictional characters is the limited amount of time we see them on screen and the few interactions we see them have with other characters.  We have a rather narrow window to assess whether real world diagnoses can be given to fictional characters.

All that being said, with anectodal evidences from other users we can see that people with ADD Can have interests in different subject and perhaps fail others because they simply aren’t as interested in them.

Another point for the ADD diagnosis is one of Jesse’s final scenes in the race against the main antagonist.  You see,  ADD is often accompanied with hyperactivity (ADHD) and one of the symptoms is poor impulse control.  Jesse fired his NOS boost too early and consequently lost the race.  Moreover, after losing the race, he panicked and ran off leading to

> The drive-by that ended his life